# Azure best practice - static web content

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

Looking for advice on best practices with Azure and hosting static web content.

In AWS world you might do this with S3 with CNAMEs and I see that Azure offers Blob storage which seems similar. A few searches seem to say that it can't be done that way then a few 'newer' results seem to suggest it can.

Other people suggest that the Azure way is to use their web apps service rather storage services

So I guess I'm asking the community for their opinion and what is the 'best practice' (yeah yeah I know that doesn't exist...but indulge me)

Many thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Azure Storage seems to be your best best if you are looking for the cheapest alternative. You can check out [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/make_it_better/2016/08/09/simple-websites-using-azure-storage-blob-service/) that demonstrates how this can be done. Custom domains are also supported using this approach.

Of course, this is very limiting and if you need more control simply go for Azure Web app.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the info and link to the blog @Milan. I ended up going with the web app services through Azure in the end. After reading the various available options such as deployment slots (for things like a dev environment) and custom domains/SSL options it seemed more straight forward to get going

Comment: Great to hear, I also think that choosing Web Apps is the better approach. All the best!